# How to use Burn Built-in Variable WixBundleUILevel in a CommandLine elements condition?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I try to route the /quiet and /passive parameters from the bootstrapper to the chained ExePackages. I found that I can add command line parameters to the Install/Repair/Uninstall command by a `<CommandLine/>` element. It has an `Condition` Attribute I want to use in the way like

```
<CommandLine Condition="WixBundleUILevel=2" InstallArgument="/q" RepairArgument="/q" UninstallArgument="/q"/>
<CommandLine Condition="WixBundleUILevel=3" InstallArgument="/passive" RepairArgument="/passive" UninstallArgument="/passive"/>
```

or

```
<CommandLine Condition="WixBundleUILevel=&quot;2&quot;" InstallArgument="/q" RepairArgument="/q" UninstallArgument="/q"/>
<CommandLine Condition="WixBundleUILevel=&quot;3&quot;" InstallArgument="/passive" RepairArgument="/passive" UninstallArgument="/passive"/>
```

As I understand from the documentation and from source code, `WixBundleUILevel` is mapped to the values of the `enum BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY`, so `2` should be the equivalent of `BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_NONE`.

The install log stated

```
Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\hb\Downloads\OLPlannerSetup.exe /passive'
...
Condition 'WixBundleUILevel="2"' evaluates to false. 
Condition 'WixBundleUILevel="3"' evaluates to false.
```

(I tried it also without quotes.)

How can I write the value of `WixBundleUILevel` to the log? Other variables like e.g. `WixBundleAction` are written to the log.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WixBundleUILevel` requires WiX v3.11.

Comment: Indeed, I was building with v3.10. Now with 3.11 it works independently of the quotes in the Expression. Also the variable and its value are listed at the end of the log.